# Issue with apple_vision_flutter and Camera controller image stream

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-vision

I'm trying to use [apple_vision_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/apple_vision_flutter) library using the `Camera` (with dependency `camera: ^0.10.5+9`) controller image stream like that:

```
await controller.startImageStream((image) async {
    Uint8List imageBytes = image.planes[0].bytes;
    final recognizeResult = await AppleVisionFlutter().recognizeText(imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    print('Recognize result: ${recognizeResult.observations.map((o) => o.textOptions.join('\n')).join('\n')}');
});
```

But the recognized results are always empty.

When I just take a picture from the `Camera`, everything works fine:

```
await controller.takePicture().then((file) async {
  final Uint8List imageData = await file.readAsBytes();
  final recognizeResult = await AppleVisionFlutter().recognizeText(imageData);
  print('Recognize result: ${recognizeResult.observations.map((o) => o.textOptions.join('\n')).join('\n')}');
});
```

Do I have to convert somehow the `ìmage` before passing the bytes to the `AppleVisionFlutter().recognizeText()` method ? Thanks for the help !